# Why is Phantom.js not removing JavaScript from my HTML after processing it?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

My Phantomjs script looks like this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
page.content = '<html><body><script>document.write("Hello World");</script></body></html>';
page.evaluate(function(){
});
page.render('export.png');
fs.write('1.html', page.content, 'w');
phantom.exit();
```

It's producing the expected PNG: one that just says "Hello World".

However, the `1.html` file it is producing is unexpected:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>document.write("Hello World");</script>
        Hello World
    </body>
</html>
```

In the browser, this produces "Hello WorldHello World".

I was hoping that `1.html` would actually be:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World
    </body>
</html>
```

I guess I could read the result back into Ruby and strip the `<script>`tags and their contents using Nokogiri, but this seems like something that Phantom.js should be doing as part of this process.

Can it do what I want?

Comment: Why are you evaluating the JS? Just leave that to the browser...

Comment: There are plenty of reasons one might want to do this. Not least for SEO. But in my case I'm rendering the JS before sending the doc to a HTML-to-PDF converter because this is a huge doc and pre-rendering the JS will reduce the workload on the HTML-to-PDF conversion engine.

Comment: In that case, just manipulate the document's DOM with Phantom to remove all `<script>` tags. There's no reason for `evaluate` to mutate the document outside of the mutations occuring as part of the evaluation.

Comment: PhantomJS behaves (nearly) as any other browser. Using `document.write` doesn't removed all other DOM elements, why would you expect that PhantomJS does this? You would have to do something like `var s = document.querySelector("script"); s.parentElement.removeChild(s);` inside `page.evaluate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted above:

PhantomJS behaves (nearly) as any other browser. Using `document.write` doesn't remove all other DOM elements, why would you expect that PhantomJS does this? You would have to do something like:

```
var s = document.querySelector("script"); 
s.parentElement.removeChild(s);
```

inside `page.evaluate`.